# created notification bars are not shown on my website

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've tested multiple plugins to add **notification bar** at the top of my WordPress website but no result yet and created notification bars are not displayed at all.

i have tested plugins such as *DW Promobar, wp-notification-bars, FireBar and etc.*

in wordpress dashboard they show a preview of the bar which i created but are not shown on website

the only plugin that worked was **top bar**

but it is very simple plugin and i need more options so in need to use other plugins for top bar.

i'm using kutshop child theme and my parent theme **kuteshop 3.0.6** which is updated.

I've no problem with other plugins and seems that the only plugins which doesn't work are notfication bar creation plugins.

i have uploaded my website's header related files here :

http://www.mediafire.com/file/zard2qrkr44z6x5/my_site_header_related_files.rar/file

Answer (score 0):

Is that possible, that you have disabled the top area by the customizer or by another way?
And you have to add your code into the header.php of your theme.
Can you check your code on another site?

Comment: no i have not disabled that. i edited my original post and put my site's header related files link to download and check. thank you